# 2005 Honda Accord coupe low beam not working

Tags: honda, accord, headlight

My son owns a 2005 Honda Accord coupe and the passenger side headlight will only work in the high beam setting. I have replaced the bulb already and it does not make a difference. We have checked the fuses, and there are no  blown fuses for the headlight circuit. I have read that a relay could be one cause of the problem, but I am not sure on where that is located. Is it in the fuse box under the hood or located elsewhere? I know that contacts in relays can become corroded, but I am not sure that is the problem. Does this seem to be a common problem with this type of Honda?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The headlight relays are located in the underhood fuse box. The relay is not a common failure, also the relay feeds both side low beam lights so it is not the failure in this case.  The ground wire is common to the high and low beam filaments, so again this is not the issue. Check for power on both sides of fuse #6 in the underhood fuse box. If power is OK there check for at least 12 volts at the red/green wire at the headlight bulb connector. 
Also test the new bulb, new does not guarantee good. Move the working left bulb to the right side.

Comment: Also check the contacts at the light bulb socket to ensure no corrosion has occurred there.

Answer (score -1):

Wow!  I was going the same path with your guy, but the Honda accord has low beams bulb socket separately. and it was stayed by its self a different socket.   DO NOT CONFUSE the low beams and high beams are the same ONE LIGHTBULB.  I went to troubleshoot like your guys. fuse, ground, voltages checked, and buy 2 or 3 bulbs make sure the light bulb is bad.
Finally,  I replace the right hold, right socket... and it works.

how stupid am I???

Comment: So these are red kidney beans or runner beans?

Answer (score -1):

There are TWO lightbulbs, 9005 for the low beams, 9006 for the high beams for the Sylvania brand.  They low beams are further in (towards the wheel), while the high beams are more easily visible.  Make sure you replace the low beam light before messing with fuses/relays.

Comment: A) the original question specified that they'd already changed the bulb. B) the bulb numbers are the same no matter who manufactures the bulb. C) this doesn't provide an answer to the question asked.